# How to map an array of arrays of arrays with objects in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary, jsx

I have an array that contains multiple arrays which contain arrays which hold objects. I know right. Sounds confusing. It looks like this

[image: This is the main array]

[image: This is how the internals of each array looks like]

[image: Each Internal Array contains objects]

Each Internal Array has two arrays, one in the 0 index and the other in the first index. These in turn also contain objects. Now my problem is how can I map from the top arrays to get to the lowests object to be able to do something like {array.name} in react.
[image: This does not work. Nothing gets rendered onto the page.]
This does not work. Nothing gets rendered onto the page

This is how the array looks like. I removed the other two internal arrays to make it look less messy.

```js
const data =
 [
   [
      [
        {name: "Michael Norman", house: "9", class: "3B2"}
      ],
      [
      {name: "Ronald Eyeson", house: "9", class: "3D3"},
      {name: "Kingsley Buadi", house: "9", class: "3N"},
      {name: "Lommo", house: "9", class: "3H"}
      ]
   ]
 ]
 
 console.log(data)
```

Comment: please post code and not pics.

Comment: Please describe the result (which you want) more details?

Comment: Please provide some actual data, preferably in a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Then you will probably get a solution in no time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run this code:

```js
const data =
 [
   [
      [
        {name: "Michael Norman", house: "9", class: "3B2"}
      ],
      [
          {name: "Ronald Eyeson", house: "9", class: "3D3"},
          {name: "Kingsley Buadi", house: "9", class: "3N"},
          {name: "Lommo", house: "9", class: "3H"}
      ]
   ],
   [
      [
        {name: "Michael Norman1", house: "9", class: "3B2"}
      ],
      [
        {name: "Ronald Eyeson1", house: "9", class: "3D3"},
        {name: "Kingsley Buadi1", house: "9", class: "3N"},
        {name: "Lommo1", house: "9", class: "3H"}
      ]
    ]
 ];
```

```html
<div>
          {Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
            return(
            <div key={key}>
              {data[key].map((dataItem) => { 
                return(
                  <div>
                  {Object.keys(dataItem).map((innerDataItem) => {
                      return (
                        <h1>{dataItem[innerDataItem].name} </h1>
                      );
                    })
                  }
                  </div>
                )
               })}
            </div>
           )
          })}
</div>
```